# React js and css animations

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm making a menu in react, but I want to make a menu like a google did this [here you can see this](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/menu). Now I'm making MenuItem, and here MenuItem can be nested inside MenuItem.

I've created such thing and it's working but I want to animate menu, I mean when you hover over this, the submenu is showing up. And I can't reach that. It's more CSS I think.

Here is my code:

```jsx
var MenuItem = React.createClass({

  getInitialState() {
      return {
          height: null
      };
  },

  componentDidMount() {
    this.size = this.refs.main.getBoundingClientRect();
    this.setState({
      height: this.size.height,
    });
  },

  extend(obj, src) {
      Object.keys(src).forEach(function(key) { obj[key] = src[key]; });
      return obj;
  },

  render(){
    var _props = this.props,
        checked,
        size,
        style = {},
        leftIcon,
        innerDivStyle = {
          padding: "10px"
        },
        rightIcon,
        MenuItemClass = "MenuItem",
        rippleOpacity,
        rippleStyle = {
          color: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
        },
        innerDivStyleMy= {
          lineHeight: this.state.height + "px",
          fontSize: _props.fontSize,
        };

    if (_props.checked) {
      checked = <FontIcon size={_props.fontSize} className="done" />;
    }

    if (_props.insetChildren) {
      checked = <FontIcon size={_props.fontSize} className="done" style={{opacity: 0}} />;
    }

    if (_props.leftIcon) {
      leftIcon = <FontIcon size={_props.fontSize} className={_props.leftIcon} />;
    }

    if (_props.rightIcon) {
      rightIcon = <FontIcon size={_props.fontSize} className={_props.rightIcon} />;
    }

    if (_props.disabled) {
      MenuItemClass = "MenuItem disabledMenuItem";
      rippleStyle.opacity = 0;
    }

    if (_props.innerDivStyle) {
      innerDivStyle = _props.innerDivStyle;
    }

    if (_props.style) {
      style = _props.style;
    }

    var innerStyle = this.extend(innerDivStyleMy, innerDivStyle);

    return(
      <div style={style}>
        <div ref="main" className={MenuItemClass} onTouchStart={_props.onTouchTap} style={innerStyle} value={_props.value} >
          <div className="MenuItemleft">{checked}{leftIcon}{_props.primaryText}</div>
          <div className="MenuItemRight">{_props.secondaryText}{rightIcon}</div>
          <Ink background={true} style={rippleStyle} opacity={rippleOpacity} />
          {_props.children}
        </div>
        <div style={{clear: "both"}}></div>
        {_props.menuItems}
      </div>
        );
  }
});

var MenuItems = React.createClass({
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="MenuItems">
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
 <MenuItem primaryText="tak" secondaryText="nie" checked="true" disabled="" insetChildren="" leftIcon="face"
 rightIcon="face" onTouchTap={()=>{alert("bbbbb");}} value="tak" innerDivStyle="" style="" fontSize={30} insetChildren=""
 menuItems={
   <MenuItems>
    <MenuItem primaryText="tak" secondaryText="nie" checked="true" leftIcon="" rightIcon="face" insetChildren="true" fontSize={20}/>
    <MenuItem primaryText="tak" secondaryText="nie" checked="true" leftIcon="" rightIcon="face" insetChildren="" fontSize={20}/>
   </MenuItems>} />,
 document.getElementById('app')
);

export default MenuItem;
```

So basically I want to show submenu when I hover over MenuItem component with `MenuItem class` So I've created a component `SubMenuitem`, it's the same as `MenuItem` but it has a different class name.

Here is the code:

```jsx
var MenuItem = React.createClass({

  getInitialState() {
      return {
          height: null
      };
  },

  componentDidMount() {
    this.size = this.refs.main.getBoundingClientRect();
    this.setState({
      height: this.size.height,
    });
  },

  extend(obj, src) {
      Object.keys(src).forEach(function(key) { obj[key] = src[key]; });
      return obj;
  },

  render(){
    var _props = this.props,
        checked,
        size,
        style = {},
        leftIcon,
        innerDivStyle = {
          padding: "10px"
        },
        rightIcon,
        MenuItemClass = "MenuItem",
        rippleOpacity,
        rippleStyle = {
          color: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
        },
        innerDivStyleMy= {
          lineHeight: this.state.height + "px",
          fontSize: _props.fontSize,
        };

    if (_props.checked) {
      checked = <FontIcon size={_props.fontSize} className="done" />;
    }

    if (_props.insetChildren) {
      checked = <FontIcon size={_props.fontSize} className="done" style={{opacity: 0}} />;
    }

    if (_props.leftIcon) {
      leftIcon = <FontIcon size={_props.fontSize} className={_props.leftIcon} />;
    }

    if (_props.rightIcon) {
      rightIcon = <FontIcon size={_props.fontSize} className={_props.rightIcon} />;
    }

    if (_props.disabled) {
      MenuItemClass = "MenuItem disabledMenuItem";
      rippleStyle.opacity = 0;
    }

    if (_props.innerDivStyle) {
      innerDivStyle = _props.innerDivStyle;
    }

    if (_props.style) {
      style = _props.style;
    }

    var innerStyle = this.extend(innerDivStyleMy, innerDivStyle);

    return(
      <div style={style}>
        <div ref="main" className={MenuItemClass} onTouchStart={_props.onTouchTap} style={innerStyle} value={_props.value} >
          <div className="MenuItemleft">{checked}{leftIcon}{_props.primaryText}</div>
          <div className="MenuItemRight">{_props.secondaryText}{rightIcon}</div>
          <Ink background={true} style={rippleStyle} opacity={rippleOpacity} />
          {_props.children}
        </div>
        <div style={{clear: "both"}}></div>
        {_props.menuItems}
      </div>
        );
  }
});

var SubMenuItem = React.createClass({

  getInitialState() {
      return {
          height: null
      };
  },

  componentDidMount() {
    this.size = this.refs.main.getBoundingClientRect();
    this.setState({
      height: this.size.height,
    });
  },

  extend(obj, src) {
      Object.keys(src).forEach(function(key) { obj[key] = src[key]; });
      return obj;
  },

  render(){
    var _props = this.props,
        checked,
        size,
        style = {},
        leftIcon,
        innerDivStyle = {
          padding: "10px"
        },
        rightIcon,
        SubMenuItemClass = "SubMenuItem",
        rippleOpacity,
        rippleStyle = {
          color: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
        },
        innerDivStyleMy= {
          lineHeight: this.state.height + "px",
          fontSize: _props.fontSize,
        };

    if (_props.checked) {
      checked = <FontIcon size={_props.fontSize} className="done" />;
    }

    if (_props.insetChildren) {
      checked = <FontIcon size={_props.fontSize} className="done" style={{opacity: 0}} />;
    }

    if (_props.leftIcon) {
      leftIcon = <FontIcon size={_props.fontSize} className={_props.leftIcon} />;
    }

    if (_props.rightIcon) {
      rightIcon = <FontIcon size={_props.fontSize} className={_props.rightIcon} />;
    }

    if (_props.disabled) {
      MenuItemClass = "SubMenuItem disabledSubMenuItem";
      rippleStyle.opacity = 0;
    }

    if (_props.innerDivStyle) {
      innerDivStyle = _props.innerDivStyle;
    }

    if (_props.style) {
      style = _props.style;
    }

    var innerStyle = this.extend(innerDivStyleMy, innerDivStyle);

    return(
      <div style={style} className="tak">
        <div ref="main" className={SubMenuItemClass} onTouchStart={_props.onTouchTap} style={innerStyle} value={_props.value} >
          <div className="MenuItemleft">{checked}{leftIcon}{_props.primaryText}</div>
          <div className="MenuItemRight">{_props.secondaryText}{rightIcon}</div>
          <Ink background={true} style={rippleStyle} opacity={rippleOpacity} />
          {_props.children}
        </div>
        <div style={{clear: "both"}}></div>
        {_props.menuItems}
      </div>
        );
  }
});

var MenuItems = React.createClass({
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="MenuItems">
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
        );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
 <MenuItem primaryText="tak" secondaryText="nie" checked="true" disabled="" insetChildren="" leftIcon="face"
 rightIcon="face" onTouchTap={()=>{alert("bbbbb");}} value="tak" innerDivStyle="" style="" fontSize={30} insetChildren=""
 menuItems={
   <MenuItems>
    <SubMenuItem primaryText="tak" secondaryText="nie" checked="true" leftIcon="" rightIcon="face" insetChildren="true" fontSize={20}/>
    <SubMenuItem primaryText="tak" secondaryText="nie" checked="true" leftIcon="" rightIcon="face" insetChildren="" fontSize={20}/>
   </MenuItems>} />,
 document.getElementById('app')
);

export default MenuItem;
```

And now I want to do such thing:

```CSS
.MenuItem:hover + .MenuItems > .SubMenuItem{
  /*the content*/
}
```

But it's not working, nothing is happening. Thanks for help :)

**EDIT**

It's how my HTML looks like:
[image]

So I don't understand why CSS I showed above doesn't work. I think that doing it only with CSS is a quicker and better way.

Comment: You need some state which will manage whether the sub menu is displayed or not and you need an onMouseOver event on the main menu which will toggle the state. The other way to do it would be to use inline styles and to have the submenuitems hidden and on mouseOver of the menu, toggle this to `display: block`. That help?

Comment: @KurtisHardy, yes, thanks, but I'm also wondering why the way I did this is not working.

Comment: I presume you get both the menu and the sub menu items displaying as i cant see anything which hides the menu items (im looking on my phone atm)?

Comment: @KurtisHardy, I've edited my question :)

Comment: I cant see the descendants of menuItems from the picture but if the first element is subMenuItem, that should work. I get my computer back on Thursday so I will put a codepen together for you.

Comment: @KurtisHardy, thanks, I've already solved a problem :) and you are right